# React remove item from array state doesnt re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to remove an item from my array state and it doesnt work the way I need it to. I get the state from a details obj from the server and save it to `name`. It is an array of objects.

```
const [name, setName] = useState(
    [...details?.name] || []
);
```

My add function works as needed:

```
const addName = () => {
    nameForm.validateFields().then(values => {
      setName([...name, values]);
      nameForm.resetFields();
      setModalVisible(false);
    });
 };
```

The remove function however doesnt. Calling the function the first i works but every time I call that function again, it uses the initial declaration of the name state. Ex, if the array is size 4 first call would remove an element and it would be size 3. If i call that function again, the name is still size 4.

```
const removeName = (obj) => {
    setName([...name.filter(i => i !== obj)]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare objects using the `!==` operator. Rather you need to compare some properties of the object. You did not say which properties your object has but let us assume they have an id property then:

```
setName([...name.filter(i => i.id !== obj.id)]);
```

would work.

Comment: I tried this and no luck. The problem is that the items do get removed but it removes it from the original state not the new one

Comment: What do you mean the original state? If you use react dev tools in Chrome do you see the state being updated at all?